# NullReference Exception in Blazors RenderTreeBuilder

Tags: html, rendering, blazor, fluentvalidation

So I'm working on a school project. I use blazor in the frontend and FluentValidation to validate forms.

First, the exception:

> ```
> System.NullReferenceException
>   HResult=0x80004003
>   Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Source=TemperBapes
>   StackTrace:
>    at TemperBapes.Pages.Register.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
> ```

I get the exception when calling the /Register page. I already had exceptions coming from the RenderTreeBuilder when my HTML was corrupt. I could always resolve the issues pretty fast so far. But I'm stuck with this one. Thats what my .razor file looks like:

```
@page "/Register"

<div class="card">
    <h5 class="card-header">Register</h5>
    <div class="card-body">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username" @bind-value="User.Username" />
                <ValidationMessage For="() => User.Username"></ValidationMessage>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="displayname">Display Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="displayname" placeholder="Enter your display name" @bind-value="User.DisplayName" />
                <ValidationMessage For="() => User.DisplayName"></ValidationMessage>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" @bind-value="User.EMail" />
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                <ValidationMessage For="() => User.EMail"></ValidationMessage>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="tele">Tel</label>
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="tele" aria-describedby="telHelp" placeholder="Enter tel" @bind-value="User.Phonenumber" />
                <small id="telHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your tel with anyone else.</small>
                <ValidationMessage For="() => User.Phonenumber"></ValidationMessage>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="passwordfield">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordfield" placeholder="Password" @bind-value="User.Password" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="(() => SendRegister())">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@code{
    public AddUserDto User { get; set; }

    public void SendRegister()
    {
        
    }
}
```

The same exception gets thrown when the FluentValidation `<ValidationMessage></ValidationMessage>` is commented out, already tried that.
Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize your `User` like

```
 public AddUserDto User { get; set; } = new AddUserDto();
```

Because your user is null, the bindings like `@bind-value="User.Password"` can't work and throws the error when used by the `RenderTreeBuilder`.

If you fix this issue, the page will render. However, you will run into the next issue.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.ValidationMessage`1[System.String] requires a cascading parameter of type EditContext. For example, you can use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.ValidationMessage`1[System.String] inside an EditForm.
System.InvalidOperationException: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.ValidationMessage`1[System.String] requires a cascading parameter of type EditContext. For example, you can use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.ValidationMessage`1[System.String] inside an EditForm.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.ValidationMessage`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].OnParametersSet()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallOnParametersSetAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
```

The message here is pretty straight forward. You need to add an `EditContext`. To do so, replace your `<form>` with a `<EditForm>` and add the `Model` Property.

```
 <EditForm Model="User">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username" @bind-value="User.Username" />
                <ValidationMessage For="() => User.Username"></ValidationMessage>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="displayname">Display Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="displayname" placeholder="Enter your display name" @bind-value="User.DisplayName" />
                <ValidationMessage For="() => User.DisplayName"></ValidationMessage>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" @bind-value="User.EMail" />
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                <ValidationMessage For="() => User.EMail"></ValidationMessage>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="tele">Tel</label>
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="tele" aria-describedby="telHelp" placeholder="Enter tel" @bind-value="User.Phonenumber" />
                <small id="telHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your tel with anyone else.</small>
                <ValidationMessage For="() => User.Phonenumber"></ValidationMessage>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="passwordfield">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordfield" placeholder="Password" @bind-value="User.Password" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="(() => SendRegister())">Submit</button>
 </EditForm>
```

To learn more about the EditForm, I recommend the following article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Wow, thank you! It's very unfortunate that Blazor does not have exact error messages for things like this. I wasn't even looking at the c# part.

Comment: You are welcome. :) What helps me often in case of a NullReferenceException (not only in Blazor) is to visualize (by pen and paper, for instance) where the object instances are and what they do. Make a "guestimate" where the error might be and comment/remove the line. Step by Step, you increase the likelihood of finding the error.

Btw. doing Blazor for school is amazing. I'd like to had visited that school too.

Comment: To add a little bit on intialization - while it's nice to initialize variables so they are not null, you can also initialize the model in the `OnInitialized`/`OnInitializedAsync` lifecycle method which can be nice if you need to pull the record from some store.